# did this paper make a mistake on anova?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, anova

The screenshot indicates that the lowest the score/value, the higher the fear level. In this case, a lower mean = higher fear, and higher mean = lower fear. Should it be that, Generation Y is significantly less afraid for fear for health?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's possible, but we'd need to see the questions to be sure. Maybe some questions were reversed?

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).